# .Net 8 DI not passing in values to specific injected services

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-8.0

I have a .Net 8 N-Tier solution with a high-level statements Program.cs within a MinimalAPI project as a startup project, which is both configuring the pipeline and also calling the Application layer.
I have an appsettings.json file which contains several sections for different configurations:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "MyConnectionStringValue"
  },
  "ThirdPartyAPIs": {
    "DeepLAuthKey": "someValue",
    "OpenAIKey": "someValue",
    "PineconeAPIKey": "someValue",
    "PineconeEnvironment": "someValue"
  },
...
}
```

In my MinimalAPI Program.cs file, I have:

```
usings ...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");    //this value gets here fine.
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();


builder.Services.Configure<ThirdPartyAPIs>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ThirdPartyAPIs"));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRunRepository, RunRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRunService, RunService>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    await next();
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.MapGet("/executerun", (IRunService runService) =>
{
    runService.Run();
})
.WithName("ExecuteRun")
.WithOpenApi();

app.MapGet("/config", (IOptionsSnapshot<ThirdPartyAPIs> externalApisOptions) => 
{
    return externalApisOptions.Value;   //the values from appsettings get here perfectly fine!
})
.WithName("GetConfig")
.WithOpenApi();;

app.Run();
```

I'm correctly getting the value from IOptionsSnapshot within my MinimalAPI through DI, but calling the run service does not render ANY values for the exact same injection:

```
public class RunService : IRunService
{
    private readonly IRunRepository _runRepository;
    private readonly ThirdPartyAPIs _externalApisOptions;
 ...
    public RunService(
        IRunRepository runRepository, 
        IOptionsSnapshot<ThirdPartyAPIs> externalApisOptions)
    {
        _runRepository = runRepository;
        _externalApisOptions = externalApisOptions.Value;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var runRepo = _runRepository.GetRuns();    //this calls the repo correctly
        var externalApis = _externalApisOptions;   //this gets the strongly-typed object but NOT any values!

    } }
```

Comment: Was not able to repro, works just fine for me. Can you please post a [mre] somewhere @ github for example?

Answer (score 0):

Upon creating a reproducible example as per requested, I noticed that the ThirdPartyAPIs instance I was injecting had the same name but was different than the instance that was registered in the DI Container. I wrongfully assumed that if the objects have the exact same structure (4 string props with the same names) that they would be copied upon injection. My mistake.